# Conditional sum from rows into a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, rolling-sum

I am looking to create a new column in panda based on the value in the row. My sample data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b'],
         "Sales":[2,3,7,1,4,3,5,6,9,10,11,8,7,13,14],
         "Week":[1,2,3,4,5,11,1,2,3,4])
```

I want a new column "Last3WeekSales" corresponding to each week, having the sum of sales for the previous 3 weeks.

NOTE: Shift() won't work here as data for some weeks is missing.

Logic which I thought:
Checking the week no. in each row, then summing up the data from w-1, w-2, w-3.

Output required:

```
   A    Week  Last3WeekSales
0  a      1       0
1  a      2       2 
2  a      3       5
3  a      4       12 
4  a      5       11
5  a     11       0
6  b      1       0
7  b      2       5
8  b      3       11
9  b      4       20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`, `shift` and `rolling`:

```
df['Last3WeekSales'] = df.groupby('A')['Sales']\
                         .apply(lambda x: x.shift(1)
                                           .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
                                           .sum())\
                         .fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   A  Sales  Week  Last3WeekSales
0  a      2     1             0.0
1  a      3     2             2.0
2  a      7     3             5.0
3  a      1     4            12.0
4  a      4     5            11.0
5  a      3     6            12.0
6  b      5     1             0.0
7  b      6     2             5.0
8  b      9     3            11.0
```

Comment: Shift() won't be really useful here as the week no is not continuous and we can't simply refer to previous 3 rows

Comment: Sorting won't help as the weeks are not in series with some weeks remaining. Updated dataset will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pandas.rolling_sum` to sum over 3 last values, and `shift(n)` to shift your column by n times (1 in your case).

if we suppose you a column 'sales' with the sales of each week, the code would be :

```
df["Last3WeekSales"] = df.groupby("A")["sales"].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x.shoft(1),3))
```

Comment: what is shoft :-)

Comment: rolling_sum is deprecated?

Comment: Shift() or Rolling_sum can't be used here as the weeks are not continuous. Edited the question accordingly.